# How to run external programs in C and make it invisible by ps command?

Tags: c++, c

I create a C program to run an external command on a CentOS system. I use `system(cmd);` to run the external command but this command can be seen by `ps` command.

Below is an example of my program `runit`:

```
./runit "mongo mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/admin"
```

it takes a string as command line argument which is used to launch a mongo shell process. In the source code of `runit`, it runs the mongo shell as below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *cmd = argv[1];
    printf("%s\n", cmd);
    if (argc > 1) {
        char *arg_end;    
        arg_end = argv[argc-1] + strlen (argv[argc-1]);
        *arg_end = ' ';
        }
    system(cmd);
    exit(100);
}
```

when I use `ps -ef | grep runit` command, it doesn't show the command line parameters. But it does show when I run `ps -ef |grep mongo`. Is there a way for me to hide the command line parameter inside `system()` method?

Comment: "only to be found by users" – Who then is supposed to *not* find the program?

Comment: Are you asking this? https://superuser.com/questions/199044/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-process-from-the-listing-of-ps-or-top-on-linux

Comment: @mkrieger1 I mean not find by `ps` command.

Comment: How would a user find the program, if not via a command-line tool such as `ps`? Should it be possible to find the program via `/proc`? Via a GUI-based tool? `top`/`htop`?

Comment: I just want to hide it from `ps` command.

Comment: You can't hide programs from the `ps` command — at least, not on a Unix-based machine.

Comment: You probably want to hide some *parts* of the command line seen by `ps`, like *mysql* does for passwords, search that (like overwriting *argv*)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. I have updated my question and put my source code. It hides my program parameters but it doesn't hide the command passed in `system` method.